# Comparison between action of two nouns

Tags: verbs, nouns

I want to say: "The cricket is much more scripted than the WWE". Should I add 'is' at the end, and if so, what is the significance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions are equally grammatical and mean the same thing. The version without *is* is a simple [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) of the version with it.

Comment: I read somewhere, that if I do not use 'is' at the end, I'd be comparing the script[ness] of cricket with the WWE itself, not with it's script[ness].

Comment: That is not a parse tree that is possible at all. (But even if it were, it would make zero sense.) My answer still stands.

Comment: @qeemaroast You may be thinking of something like "He likes pizza more than I" versus "He likes pizza more than me". The first parses to "He likes pizza more than I (like pizza)" while the second parses to "He likes pizza more than (he likes) me" -- which are two very different sentences. :)

Comment: And the *is* doesn't have to go at the end either. Although perhaps archaic or overly formal it could also be: "*... than is the WWE*"  On a different note I think "*The* cricket" sounds strange to me alongside *the WWE*.  If WWE refers to wrestling, then I'd assume *cricket* refers to the game, and in that case I think you don't want *The*- it's just *Cricket* or "*The game of Cricket*"